# click the check box I need to add an image in the next column for that particular row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When I click the check box I need to add an image in the next column for that particular row. I use the `addClass()` method to the code and target `td`. However it's adding everywhere.

Can you tell me how to fix it? I'm providing my code below

http://jsfiddle.net/wj1z3dnp/6/

```js
$(document).on('change', '#checkIDGrid', function() {
  alert("I am inside change");
  $("td").addClass("timeGrad1");

  if (this.checked) {
    var returnVal = confirm("Are you sure?");
    $(this).prop("checked", returnVal);
  }
  // $('#textbox1').val(this.checked);        
});
```

Comment: Please use actual paragraphs when describing your issue. It makes it much clearer to read and understand. This is not the first time I've seen you use unnecessary bullet points.

Comment: The issue itself is because you're using `$('td')` to select all the elements. You  need to change that selector to whatever it needs to be. instead. You've not told use what you *do* want to add the class to

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the class to all of your `td` elements, try to be more specific with your selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can get next column for that particular row using this code.

`$(this).closest('td').next('td');`

Then you can add class

`$(this).closest('td').next('td').addClass("timeGrad1");`

Comment: thanks for your reply...its working...suppose if there are ten columns and I wanted to show in the sixth column the image...how can I show

Comment: You can use `$(this).closest('td').nextAll('td').slice(5, 6).addClass("timeGrad1");` 

Use .nextAll instead of .next to get all following siblings, and then use .slice to narrow that down to a range.
so from ten columns to the sixth column we need next 5 times and show upto 6.

Comment: @arkr  is it working? If any problem please lets me know.

Comment: @arkr Can you please mark this answer correct if answered is useful.